# Execute internal server script in grafana

Tags: scripting, grafana

I would like to know how to execute a script in response to an alert in Grafana. 
I want to execute the script in a shell when the temperature is greater than 25C. The script connects to an ESX server and turns off all VM's.

I've created the script that connects to the ESX server, but I'm not sure how to call it from Grafana.

Comment: Your problem is unclear. Please elaborate on what you're trying to achieve, what you've tried so far and where you got stuck. Also, please use full sentences and don't substitute numbers for words.

Comment: i change my first post

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Alert Webhook notifier](http://docs.grafana.org/alerting/notifications/#webhook). It sends a json document to the webhook url every time an alert is triggered.

You will need to build some sort of backend service (in any language/web framework) that can listen to HTTP requests. This service would take in the JSON document, parse it and then shell out to execute your script.